# Echo or print an declared variable in a pdo query

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

So i have this query and i want it to echo it or print it somehow.

```
$my_query = $db->prepare("DECLARE @item varbinary(1728); SET @item = (SELECT Inventory FROM Character WHERE Name='CharName'); print @item");
$my_query->execute();
$my_query = $my_query->fetch();


echo  $my_query[0] // give me error
```

But is not working is giving me error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[24000]: Invalid cursor state: 0
```

Comment: Did you try googling the error message? https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=SQLSTATE[24000]%3A+Invalid+cursor+state%3A+0 Also, you really should parameterize your queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

You cannot call multiples queries in `prepare()` method, only one.

**Solution:**

Move the SQL into a stored procedure, then call the stored procedure to return the value